# Updating Symfony 2.4 : "Rendering a fragment can only be done when handling a Request."

Tags: symfony, request, twig, updating, symfony-2.4

Since I migrated to Symfony 2.4, I'm getting the following error message :

> Rendering a fragment can only be done when handling a Request.

It's happening because, on some pages, I'm rendering some templates with Twig inside some pages which are handled by another older framework, by doing `$sf2->container->get('twig')->render("MyBundle::my-template.html.twig");`.

So yes, that's right that Symfony 2 isn't handling those requests, but I still want to render those templates with Twig ! Why can't I do that (anymore) ?! And how to fix that ?

Here is the code I'm executing to "boot" SF2 in my older project :

```
$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../../../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
Debug::enable();
require_once __DIR__.'/../../../app/AppKernel.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('bootstrap', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$kernel->boot();
$kernel->getContainer()->enterScope('request');
$kernel->getContainer()->set('request', $request, 'request');
$this->container = $kernel->getContainer();
```

EDIT : By the way, it might be related to that : [Symfony 2.4 Rendering a controller in TWIG throws "Rendering a fragment can only be done when handling a Request." Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457807/symfony-2-4-rendering-a-controller-in-twig-throws-rendering-a-fragment-can-only) .
Though, I don't want to downgrade to Symfony 2.3, and deleting the `vendor` directory didn't fix my problem.

EDIT² : I found out that the problem is because of the new [RequestStack](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack).

In `HttpKernel`, `handleRaw(Request $request, $type = self::MASTER_REQUEST)` normally push the request to the RequestStack (`$this->requestStack->push($request);`). So if I add a public method `pushRequestStack($request)` to the `HttpKernel` it works.. But how could I do it properly ? I don't find any public method able to get the `$requestStack` from `HttpKernel` (so I can push the request externally)..

And I can't use the "normal" method (`$kernel->handle($request)`) because it would throw some exceptions, for example for the route that doesn't exist, or also for the session that has already been started by PHP..

**In conclusion, is there any way to "push" my/any request to the requestStack without completly handling the request ?**

Comment: should probably be `$kernel->getContainer()->set('request', Request::createFromGlobals(), 'request');` otherwise why are you creating the `$request` variable ?

Comment: Yes that was a mistake, but it actually throws the same error doing that..

Comment: I just updated my original post, now I know where the problem is from, I just don't know how to get round it !

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have been using the same snippet for a long time and it is not working now.

Comment: No I didn't. Actually, instead of wasting too much time looking for a solution, I chose to use only the twig template rendering from SF2 in my older framework.. But I don't even have access to `path()` or `render()`.

Answer (score 6):

You have to push a new Request in the "request_stack" from your Sf2 command.

```
 $this->getContainer()->get('request_stack')->push(Request::createFromGlobals());
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved this by rebuilding the bootstrap with this command:

```
php vendor/bundles/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php app
```

Comment: I have tried the same, but it doesn't solve my problem. Although I am using a Symfony 2.7, but I have rebuilt the same bootstrap.